# Get index of the results on Pandas rolling_max applied to another column

Tags: pandas, indexing, max, rolling-computation

For a stock price timeseries, I applied rolling_max on 'Adj Close' for the column '52 weeks High'. I would like to have another column "52 weeks High Date' to show the date where the rolling max '52 weeks High' was reached. Appreciate help on the code for this. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

start = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1) # yyyy, m, d
df_0700 = pdr.DataReader('0700.HK', 'yahoo', start=start)

df_0700['52 weeks High'] = df_0700['Adj Close'].asfreq('D').rolling(window=52*7, min_periods=1).max()
```

I got error when tried below two codes;

```
df_0700['52 weeks High Date'] = df_0700[df_0700['Adj Close'].asfreq('D').rolling(window=52*7, min_periods=1).max()].index

df_0700['52 weeks High Date'] = np.where(df_0700['Adj Close'].rolling(window=52*7, min_periods=1).max().index.values)
```

[image]

I tried the below code and it seem to give the desired data but just wondering if there's any better / efficient way

```
for i in range(len(df_0700)):
    df_0700['52 weeks High Date'][i] = df_0700[ df_0700['Adj Close'] == df_0700['52 weeks High'][i] ].index
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Edwin what does the error says?

Comment: for the first one; KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([111.09674072265625, 111.09674072265625, 111.09674072265625, 111.78616333007812,  118.1880111694336, 122.52157592773438, 125.37777709960938, 125.37777709960938, 125.37777709960938, 125.37777709960938,\n              ...\n              446.20001220703125, 446.20001220703125, 446.20001220703125, 446.20001220703125, 446.20001220703125, 446.20001220703125, 448.79998779296875,  450.6000061035156,              458.0,  460.3999938964844], dtype='float64', length=1996)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index for the 2nd code; df_0700['52 weeks High Date'] = np.where(df_0700['Adj Close'].rolling(window=52*7, min_periods=1).max().index.values)

Comment: I tried the below code and it seem to give the desired data but just wondering if there's any better / efficient way

for i in range(len(df_0700)):
    df_0700['52 weeks High Date'][i] = df_0700[ df_0700['Adj Close'] == df_0700['52 weeks High'][i] ].index

Comment: Sorry, I tried lambda function but it does not retain the date index. I think your For loop is the best answer now. Hopefully someone else can offer a solution.

Comment: no prob. thank you for your help!

Comment: as i'm comparing df_0700[ df_0700['Adj Close'] == df_0700['52 weeks High'][i] ], i'm just thinkign what if there are more than 1 of the same price value